# Le mot 'mazette' et son emploi

Tags: usage, noms, interjections

Pourquoi le substantif 'mazette' (selon wiki) est considéré désuet ? Il y a aussi l'interjection mazette exprimant la surprise, l'étonnement, etc. Cette interjection est-elle répandue partout en France ?

Comment: Personnellement, tu viens de me faire découvrir le mot, je ne l'ai jamais entendu dans ma vie, je comprends qu'il soit mentionné comme désuet. Où l'as-tu trouvé?

Comment: @Kenichi-san On peut en trouver un exemple comme substantif dans [_Cyrano de Bergerac_](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_(Rostand)/Acte_II) : « [...] Travailler à se construire un nom / Sur un sonnet, au lieu d’en faire d’autres ? Non, /
Merci ! Ne découvrir du talent qu’aux mazettes ? /
Être terrorisé par de vagues gazettes, [...] ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je n'ai jamais entendu le mot « mazette » employé comme substantif de ma vie (et elle est déjà bien longue). Je suis prêt à parier que la majorité des francophones de France ne le connaissent pas dans ce sens.

Petite recherche dans [google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=mazette&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&ei=aMZLXbq5BJK_lwT_vJf4CQ&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwi6jcbh1_LjAhWS34UKHX_eBZ84ChDx0wMIVQ&biw=1853&bih=903&dpr=1). Les 19 résultats pour le XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle sont essentiellement l'interjection ou l'emploi comme nom propre. Les 3 résultats comme nom commun ne sont que des reproductions d’occurrences plus anciennes. Parmi les 23 résultats pour le XX<sup>e</sup> siècle les seuls renvois sous forme de nom commun ne sont que des renvois encyclopédiques de signalements d'avant le XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.
Ceci dit le TLF a deux entrées datant du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle (une pour chaque sens).

J'ai cherché d'où venait ce mot apparu au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle. Deux étymologies sont évoquées, une suggère un emploi métaphorique de *mesette* (« mésange » en dialectes normand et franc-comtois), l'autre un diminutif de l'ancien français *maez* (mauvais) mais Le DHLF signale que cette « hypothèse [bien que] cohérente [...] manque d'observation ».

Le DHLF dit bien que « [le mot] n'est plus guère employé qu'en interjection (1834) pour marquer surprise ou admiration ».

Comme interjection je pense qu'elle est connue de la majorité des français mais je ne l'entends pas souvent, jamais entendu dans le sud-ouest de la France où j'ai longtemps vécu, plus souvent en Normandie, donc il peut rester des emplois régionaux (le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* signale l'emploi interjectif comme un régionalisme).

Voici un extrait d'une chronique sur la langue française d'un grand quotidien français, le sujet du [billet](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/2016/08/04/37002-20160804ARTFIG00082-waouh-d-o-viens-tu.php) est l'interjection  *Waouh*:

> La langue évolue et nous pouvons donc remplacer, si nous en avons envie - aucune obligation -, par «Waouh» ou le délicieux «Mazette», qui a le même sens et tant de charme désuet...

(J'ai reproduit tel quel mais je pense qu'il y a une faute de frappe - disons un mot en trop : « ou »).

---

Pour tempérer ce que je dis plus haut, je signale que je viens de [trouver une phrase](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mazette.1771481/) d'un roman écrit au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle qui emploi le mot « mazette » comme substantif (personne maladroite).

> Je n'étais pas une mazette mais une fille bien baignée et poudrée.

La phrase est tirée d'un roman de [Marie-Célie Agnant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie-C%C3%A9lie_Agnant) publié en 1995 (*La Dot de Sara*). L'écrivaine Québécoise y raconte une enfance passé en Haïti où une des langues officielles est le français.

Answer (score 4):

Le substantif a disparu du vocabulaire de la grande majorité des gens (je ne le connaissais pas moi-même), peut-être parce que les chevaux ont disparu de notre quotidien.

L'interjection *mazette* est encore souvent connue mais n'est plus utilisée qu'humoristiquement dans mon entourage, justement pour son côté désuet.

Un sondage non représentatif sur une personne de douze ans a donné cette réponse sans appel :

> Je connais, mais c'est un mot de vieux...

Comment: Je connais des gens qui utilisent *mazette* (comme interjection, je ne connaissais pas le substantif non plus), et ce n'est pas humoristique. C'est probablement un régionalisme, je l'associe au sud-ouest.

Comment: @Gilles Personnellement je l'ai entendu plus souvent en Normandie que dans le sud-ouest.

Comment: Petite pierre belge à l'édifice: l'emploi comme interjection est ici aussi le seul que j'aie jamais connu, et effectivement relativement désuet.

Answer (score 3):

Comme c'est moi qui l'ai employé dans un post, je réponds.  Les emplois où *mazette* a un sens plein dans le TLFi, je ne les connaissais pas du tout.  Comme interjection, c'est peut-être un méridionalisme.  Je la tiens d'une amie dauphinoise qui l'utilise relativement souvent.

Answer (score 1):

Ce terme est encore assez souvent utilisé aux Échecs, où il signifie *débutant*, par exemple dans la fameuse expression

```
 Mazette voit échec, mazette fait échec
```

En revanche, je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme, utilisé comme substantif, dans un autre contexte.

Comme interjection, il est parfois utilisé effectivement, mais dans un sens un peu ironique, à cause de son caractère désuet justement.

Answer (score 0):

Complément aux excellentes réponses. Évidement le substantif est peu connu :

http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11692

http://ffjd.fr/forum/sujet.php?id_sujet=42469